# Celery how instantly kill running task

Tags: python, django, celery

i want to implement api endpoint for start/stop button with celery
(when is running, on backend in while(True) loop do some work)

celery version 4.4.6. As broker i use rabbit

##### i stuck with task revoking(i need just instantly kill task)

i use this code for that(but it not works)

```
app.control.revoke(started_task.id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')
```

my task looks like that

```
async def _grind():
    count = 1
    while True:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        # here are many parrallel aihttp requests and database writes...

@shared_task(bind=True)
def grind(self):
    asyncio.run(_grind())
```

and i need *is_running* state to provide him to my frontend

##### my vain tries...

the idea is that when you click on the stop at the task entry, a signal is set to stop and while saving, I cause an exception that interrupts the execution of the task (but the save signal never works)

```
class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TaskType.choices)
    signal = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TaskSignal.choices, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='tasks', on_delete=CASCADE)


@shared_task(bind=True)
def grind(self):
    task_id = self.request.id

    def cancel_task(instance: Task, **kwargs):
        print('Never trigger')
        if instance.id == task_id and instance.signal == TaskSignal.STOP:
            post_save.disconnect(cancel_task, sender=Task)
            instance.delete()
            raise Ignore()

    post_save.connect(cancel_task, sender=Task)


    count = 1
    while True:
        count += 1
        print(count)

# ---- on start-stop click
def toggle_grind(user: CustomUser):
    started_task = Task.objects.filter(type=TaskType.GRIND, user=user).first()

    if started_task:
       started_task.signal = TaskSignal.STOP
       started_task.save()
       #  app.control.revoke(started_task.id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')
       return False
    else:
        task_id = grind.apply_async().id
        Task.objects.create(
            id=task_id,
            type=TaskType.GRIND,
            user=user
        )
        return True
```

Comment: I think `_grind()` either should be async or a generator for asyncio to run it. Is it a typo?

Comment: fixed this typo

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "but it not works" -- what exactly does not work? Do you get an error? Or what?

Comment: revoke() does nothing and task just continue excecution(I was expecting to cancel the task), and there is no error or exception, just nothing happens